# Как изменить колонки товаров в Opencart2

Tags: opencart

Помогите нужно сделать так что бы товар на главной и на других страницах где отображается товар был в 3-ех колонках а не в 4-ех дизайн стандартный opencart версии 2

Answer (score 1):

Вывести какой-нибудь модуль в левую или правую колонку, на главную страницу и категории. Или править кучу .tpl файлов.

На главную товары просто так не выводятся сами по себе, их разные модули выводят: рекомендуемые товары, новинки, акции и т.д.. У каждого модуля свой .tpl шаблон.

Например, по умолчанию на главную выводится модуль рекомендуемые товары, у него шаблон /catalog/view/theme/default/template/module/featured.tpl вот его и правим. А там стандартная сетка [Bootstrap3](http://bootstrap-3.ru/css.php#grid). Ищем в featured.tpl

```
<div class="product-layout col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
```

и меняем на

```
<div class="product-layout col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
```

Подобным образом и остальные шаблоны модулей, категории и всего остального.

Answer (score 0):

Меняйте настройки в разделе *Дополнения* → *Модули*

Answer (score 0):

catalog/view/theme/default/template/common/home.tpl

12 строчка цифру 4 заменить на желаемое количество колонок.

Comment: У вас точно _версия 2_ и _стандартная тема_?